# How do I fix issues with emphasis in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-emphasis

I am trying to configure org-emphasis-regexp-components. My current configuration for the variable is the following...

```
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
    (setcar org-emphasis-regexp-components            "     \t('\"{[:alpha:]:-“”\[\\") ;; prematch 
    (setcar (nthcdr 1 org-emphasis-regexp-components) "\] [:alpha:]-   _^[:space:]:\t.,!?;''“”\")}/\\“”") ;; postmatch
    (setcar (nthcdr 2 org-emphasis-regexp-components) "    \t\r\n,\"") ;; forbidden
    (setcar (nthcdr 3 org-emphasis-regexp-components) ".") ;; body
    (setcar (nthcdr 4 org-emphasis-regexp-components) 10) ;; max newlines
    (org-set-emph-re 'org-emphasis-regexp-components org-emphasis-regexp-components))
```

I have two issues:

- I end up with emphasis across manually broken lines, ie.

```
This_line
Text between
This_line
```

Will result in the line "Text between" getting emphasized which is not what I want. I thought by adding `\n` to the list of forbidden characters that this would be fixed, but it is not.

- I cannot mix emphasis properly ie.
  `*T*his *should* be bold` should bold "T", and "should", but instead bolds "This should"

--**update**--

I changed my customization to

```
(setq org-emphasis-regexp-components '(
"-—[:space:][:alnum:]('\"{"         ;; prematch 
"-[:space:][:alnum:].,:!?;'\")}\\[" ;; postmatch 
"[:space:]"                          ;; forbidden 
"."                                  ;; body 1))
```

So it looks like setting the max-newlines to 1 fixed my first issue. The issue of *T*his *should* resulting in This should instead of bolding just T and should remains.

To describe more what I want, I hope to have emphasis work more closely to how modern markdown editors do.

- For example, in Typora, emphasis can be applied within a word itself, around groups of words on the same line, along groups of words on wrapped lines, but not across manually added lines.
- Also, if possible, the emphasis should be have the ability to be preceeded by dashes, ie. this-/word/, should italicize word and also emphasized words should be able to be preceded or superseded by a slash, ie. *bolded*/*words* should only bold bolded and words, I realize this would cause an issue with italics which leads to me also wanting to somehow change the emphasis markers org uses (which I know now is not possible anymore).
- Lastly I'd like to somehow make it possible to prevent any other types of emphasis inside verbatim environments ie. `=(+2 (+ 1 1))=` should not result in the strike-through of 2 and the parentheses.

Comment: Why are you using `setcar`: Do you for some reason need to modify the list structure? (If not, don't do that, would be my first suggestion.)

Comment: I used `setcar` because I've seen other users and answers modify this variable in such a way. The basis for my customization of this variable is from [this post](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4378#issuecomment-366763807). What should I do instead?

Comment: That's a bad example. You might want to use `setcar` if you are doing surgery on  a list and you want to change a specific element without disturbing anything around it. But here you are constructing the list from the ground up: just use `list` to construct it. BTW, you should do `C-h v org-emphasis-regexp-components` and read it carefully. This variable has caused no end of grief to users and maintainers alike and there is serious talk about chucking the whole thing out (IIRC).

Comment: In your first example, you say what you don't want, but never mention what you *do* want. What is the complete set of your requirements?

Comment: @NickD I have read through `C-h v org-emphasis-regexp-components` many times and I still feel very confused. For example, given the line `*T*his what are my characters for pre and post match. I also do not understand what a forbidden character actually is or what adding something to the forbidden character list does. Regarding the reconstruction of my code, should I just replace each instance of `setcar` with `list`?

Comment: Regarding what I want, I suppose it would be something close to what most markdown editors have. For example, in Typora, emphasis can be applied within a word itself, around groups of words on the same line, along groups of words on wrapped lines, but not across manually added lines.

Comment: Also, if possible, the emphasis should be have the ability to be preceeded by dashes, ie. `this-/word/`, should italicize *word* and also emphasized words should be able to be preceded or superseded by a slash, ie. `*bolded*/*words*` should only bold *bolded* and *words*, I realize this would cause an issue with italics which leads to me also wanting to somehow change the emphasis markers org uses (which I know now is not possible anymore).

Comment: I changed my customization to

```(setq org-emphasis-regexp-components
'("-—[:space:][:alnum:]('\"{"         ;; prematch
"-[:space:][:alnum:].,:!?;'\")}\\[" ;; postmatch
"[:space:]"                ;; forbidden
"."                        ;; body
1))```.

It looks like setting the max-newlines to 1 fixed my first issue. The issue of `*T*his *should*` resulting in *This should* instead of bolding just *T* and *should* remains.

Comment: Wrt `setcar`: *"other users and answers modify this variable in such a way"*. No. `setcar` does not modify a variable. It modifies list structure. That's "destructive" modification. Don't use it unless you know what you're doing with it and why you're doing it.

Comment: @Drew I think I fixed that issue by using `setq` instead.

Comment: You should edit your question to add all the information from the comments. The question needs to stand on its own. That avoids long conversations in comments, but more importantly, all of the important information is in the question where it belongs and whoever decides to answer doesn't have to dig through all the comments to figure out what is going on. BTW, AFAIK comments are not searchable so they are not useful for finding questions in the future.

Comment: What @NickD said. Edit the question to ask everything you need to ask, providing all context and details. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I'm pretty sure I did that.

Comment: OK, if so, thanks. I didn't check.